# PhoneGap - hide back button on tab bar page switch

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've been meddling with Obj-C for a while now, and even though i have gotten rather familiar with it, I wanted to give PhoneGap a chance since I'm working with a web development team and PhoneGap (if it proves to be strong enough) could liberate me from being the go-to guy when an app gets ordered.

So, my whole day yesterday was studying and examples, I have a pretty good grasp of how it works; Today i am diving a bit deeper though:

1) First of all, i found out that

```
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn= true;
```

adds a back button making navigation easier in just one line. Nifty indeed! But, since i have installed the NativeControls plugin, and have an actual UITabBar, with code such as:

```
var NativeControls = window.plugins.nativeControls;
NativeControls.createTabBar();  
NativeControls.createTabBarItem("items","items","tabButton:Items",{"onSelect":
                                function(){
                                $.mobile.changePage( "#page1", { transition: "none"} );
                                 }});
NativeControls.createTabBarItem("faq","faq","tabButton:F.A.Q.",{"onSelect":
                                function(){
                                $.mobile.changePage( "#page2", { transition: "none"} );
                                }});
NativeControls.showTabBar();
NativeControls.showTabBarItems("items","faq");
NativeControls.selectTabBarItem("book");
```

how do I hide the "Back" button when a transition occurs due to the TabBar?

2) Offtopic but it's something I will have to face in the near future, if anyone has any resources of knowledge on how to create divs/#pages dynamically according to the item clicked with a `<ul>` of `<li>`s as to mimic the behaviour of a UITableView, I'd be happy if you could share. My model would be something like:

user clicks on category "cell" -> ping server for products or sub-categories or whatever it contains -> construct "on the fly" a new div/#page containing a `<ul>` of `<li>`s that are also bound (via their class hopefully) to the same (recurring?) function.

Also, would a "Back" button work in such a model?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the code you are talking about is JQueryMobile which really has nothing to do with PhoneGap.... I've written multiple PhoneGap applications without ever using JQM!

Either way, I personally don't use the JQM Back button as I've found they can sometimes be confusing (depending of course on your app layout) and not always reliable. I tend to always place an icon with a description for the user of where this button will take them to.

Regarding dynamic pages in JQM, have a look at their [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html) where they talk about this.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link, I'll dive into it straight ahead.

I want to mimic iOS's UINavigationController and UITableView behaviour. How would you go about doing that yourself without using JQMs back button?

Comment: you would just call your nativeControls plugin setting the left button to whichever feels right depending on the current page... Of course you could also just set it to call back to your code with a javascript call of history.back() which will basically just return the user to whatever he did before (in case you application flow is so dynamic that you are sharing pages and the back could be anything)